# I Don't understand how to call PHP function with HTML using AJAX (JQuery)

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to call a function when the user click on the related button.

The button is located in the directory views/TableauDeBord.php and here is the code (that don't work).

```php
class TableauDeBord
{
    public function show():void
    {
        ob_start();
        ?>
```

```html
<!--What I was trying to do : -->
<!--            <script type="text/javascript">-->
<!--                JQuery.Ajax({-->
<!--                    type:"POST",-->
<!--                    url:'app/controllers/TableauDeBord.php'-->
<!--                    dataType:'json',-->
<!--                    data: {functionname: 'test'},-->
<!--                    -->
<!--                })-->
<!--            </script>-->

        <form method="post">
            <input type="button" name="creerSalle" value="creerSalle" onclick=""/>
        </form>
```

```php
        <?php
        (new ModelePage('Tableau De Bord', ob_get_clean(), 'tableauDeBord'))->show();
    }
}
```

On click I want to call one of the function/method that are located in controllers/TableauDeBord.php

Here is for example the function I want to call :

```php
    public static function test():void
    {
        echo 'called the test function';
    }
```

In the end I will have 3 buttons that will mostly do SQL queries in PHP.

I Tried stuff with JQuery and AJAX stuff but I don't understand how to call the JQuery function in the script in views/TableauDeBord.php

In controllers/TableauDeBord.php I tried somethin with switch case using post

```php
switch ($_POST['functionname']){
    case 'test':
        TableauDeBord::test();
        break;
}
```

In any case I want an explanation of how to call a function according to my code structure. And if you provide me code I would like to know where to write it because in other topic I saw people usually don't say where you should put code so i'm lost (and sad)

notes : I'm using MVCfor my whole site that's why i'm only using class everywhere and not just php file.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Ajax can not call a PHP function! Only PHP can do. But you can call a specific route provided by PHP or pass a parameter for example as action which is parsed by PHP calling the function.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry but I did not understand what you said, what do you mean by "call a specific route"

Comment: Can you please add the actual code you are running? Where/how do you expect the JS to be invoked here? This seems close but would need to read the response, `done(function( response ) {`...assuming your JS is valid and invoked. Your `JSON` data type will also fail as `echo 'called the test function'` is not JSON.

Comment: I want this button, located in views/TableauDeBord.php: 
```lang-html
<form method="post">
            <input type="button" name="creerSalle" value="creerSalle" onclick=""/>
        </form>
```
to run the function located in controllers/TableauDeBord.php :
```lang-php
public function creerNouvelleSession()
    {
        BaseDeDonnee::resetScore();
        BaseDeDonnee::miseAJourDuCodeJeu($this->generateurNomAleatoire(4));
    }
```
I know nothing about JS that's why i'm having lot of issues, that's why i may ask more general answer.

Comment: 1) You'll need some JavaScript code, which runs in the browser, that activates when the button is clicked and uses AJAX to send a web request to the server 2) You'll need some PHP code, which runs on the server, to respond to that AJAX web request and returns something (typically JSON) in a web response 3) You'll need some more JavaScript code, which runs in the browser, that deals with the AJAX response - for example updating some element on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run a specific function in an PHP file using AJAX with Jquery, however you can call a full PHP file to be executed. In your case you would be creating a new PHP file `yourfile.php` and paste the function's code into there.

Generally speaking this is the normal flow you should be using:

[image: Diagram]

You can create a click listener for the "creerSalle" button the following way:

```
<input type="button" name="creerSalle" value="creerSalle" id="creerSalleButton">

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#creerSalleButton').click(function() {
      alert('Button clicked!');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Inside this event listener you can then call `yourfile.php` with the parameters using [Jquery AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp). Here is an example:

```
var postData = {
  "parameter": "value"
};

// Request type "POST"
$.post("yourfile.php", postData, function(response) {
  // This section handles your response from yourfile.php
  console.log(response);
}, "json")
.fail(function(error) {
  // If an error occurs, this function is called
  console.error("Error:", error.responseText);
});
```

To read these values given to the file, you need to use the $_GET or $_POST variables in PHP. This depends on what [type of request](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/http-request-methods-explained/) you use.

Example on how to handle POST request:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST") {
   echo json_encode(["status" => "error", "message" => "Please use POST"]);
   return;
}
if(empty($_POST["property"])) {
   echo json_encode(["status" => "error", "message" => "Missing value \"property\""]);
   return;
}

// Request well formed

// Process data

echo json_encode(["status" => "success", "message" => "Data received successfully"]);
```

?>

Comment: Thank you a lot you helped me to understand how all of this work. However I wanted to know, in case (it is my case actually), I do not want to use neither post nor get method, I just want to run a php file without any input. What am I supposed to do in the listener ? (and php file if I have to do something).

Comment: @Mathisov In this case you don’t have to give any input (or body content), however you’ll still need to use GET or POST. This is just sending a request basically. The server still has to know that there has been an action done by the client/frontend and this is the way of telling it. Imagine you visit google.com, doing this your computer sends a GET request to google.com telling it to deliver your page. There is no input needed here as well. The site knows what to do because you’ve sent the request. You can take my AJAX POST example and just leave the postData variable empty and it work out.

Comment: @Mathisov Why not use GET or POST? You could use any HTTP method, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods, https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Answer (score 1):

An AJAX request doesn't run a function on the server, it just requests a URL. For the most part, loading a URL over AJAX just works like loading a normal page, PHP doesn't care about the type of request.

Here's a trick I find generally helps understand this: open the URL you're trying to fetch via AJAX in a new browser tab; whatever you see there is what your JavaScript will get back.

So if you've already got an MVC framework set up for full pages, the URLs you load over AJAX can use exactly the same system.